# Many-to-One в TypeOrm

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

Всем доброго времени суток.
На проекте используется TypeOrm.

Пытаюсь настроить отношения между таблицами (вроде все в соответствии с докой).

Мои модели:

```
@Entity("order")
export class OrderEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public ID!: number;

    @Column()
    public locator: string;

    ...

    @OneToMany(() => OrderPassenger, (passenger) => passenger.order_id)
    public passengers: OrderPassenger[];


    public static TEST(id: number)
    {
        return this.createQueryBuilder("order")
            .select("order.locator")
            .leftJoinAndSelect("order.passengers", "passenger")
            .where("order.ID = :id", { id })
            .getMany();

     /* первый вариант

        return this.find({
            relations: ["passengers"],
            where: {ID: id},
        });
     */
    }

}
```

и еще

```
@Entity("order_passengers")
export class OrderPassenger extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public ID!: number;

    @Column()
    public name_first: string;

    ...

    @ManyToOne(() => OrderEntity, (order) => order.passengers)
    public order: OrderEntity;

}
```

Пытаюсь выполнить метод TEST, получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined
```

Еще пробовал добавлять декоратор JoinColumn вместе с OneToMany и ManyToOne, результат тот же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderPassenger.order` - сюда точно пробовал добавлять `JoinColumn`?

`@OneToMany(() => OrderPassenger, (passenger) => passenger.order_id)`
Вместо order_id, должен быть order - ORM мапается на поля класса, а не базы.

Comment: попробовал. заработало. спасибо) но по правде говоря понял что надо сделать по коду, а вот текстовое описание по поводу того, куда мапается ОРМ - очень мутное. было бы здорово его немного переписать.